# Facebook comments count in fbml doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook

so basically can't get comment count to work using html5 boxes:

html:

```
<fb:comments-count href="http://example.com"></fb:comments-count> comments
```

JS SDK is included like this:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=233176953542656&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And.. instead of querying a normal graph comments endpoint it executed an fql query `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?callback...` which in response gave this:

```
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.f2670b77d1e44b({
    "error": {
        "message":"An access token is required to request this resource.",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":104
    }
})
```

So I either have to use iframe method to load comment count (10s of iframes per page.. it's a lot in my opinion) or ask user to auth on facebook to see comment number?

Isn't there another way other than writing my own wrapper to call graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now wrote an own graph wrapper:

html:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
            <span class="ext-fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com"></span> comments
</a>
```

graph wrapper to put into an end of template:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var items = {};
        var urls = [];
        $('.ext-fb-comments-count').each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            var href = obj.data('href');
            items[ href ] = obj;
            urls.push(encodeURI(href));
        });
        urls.length && $.get('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + urls.join(','), null, function(r){
                for(key in r) items[key].html( r[key].comments?r[key].comments:'0' );
            });
    })();
</script>
```

It looks for elements with class 'ext-fb-comments-count' and if finds any - loads comment count into them.

demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2u54Q/

live result: http://dyatlovprojects.com/startups/